# How can I "touch" a php session during long running script

Tags: php, session

Our PHP project has a maintenance script that runs at specific intervals and executes a series of tasks based on individual schedules, think of it as `CRON` for php.

The issue I'm running into is, some of the tasks that come up at certain intervals run for periods longer than our hardened session length (30 min), and so the session expires during the course of that task, ending things prematurely.

FYI: I'm not talking about script run-time limits, we already utilize `set_time_limit()` to allow for long running processes.

**Question: is there a way to 'touch' a session *during* the execution of a script in a way that will reset the session expiry time? i.e. Is *setting* a session var suitable, or is there a specific PHP function needed to accomplish this?**

---

To be more specific we have a single actual `CRON` job which runs every minute:

```
* * * * * user curl -XGET https://domain.com/maintenance.php
```

... which in turn uses our internal system for looking up tasks scheduled to run at that time, some of these tasks are short and simple, some are long and complex.  It's during the long complex (>30min runtime) ones that the above issue is happening.

---

**EDIT:** To sum up the many comments below...

1. We want to avoid issuing additional RPC's to accomplish this, what I'm looking for is a solution like an imaginary `touch_session()`.
2. I believe we can rule out changing session values as an option because the changes aren't recorded in the session until the request is closed, which in our case is too late.
3. We're using the DB for session management, so we might simply be able to write our own `touch_session()` method which can be called and simply uses a SQL query to update the timestamp a la `UPDATE sessions SET expiration = '###' WHERE Session_ID = 'abc123';`. **Are there any pitfalls to this?**

**If not any of the above, are there other options that do not require further rpc's?**

Comment: So, you're running the script with a cron job or something else? Can you explain how this is related to sessions? Could you explain a little what the problem actually is?

Comment: Session timeout does not terminate the script execution; *max\_execution\_time* is the only limit.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Added specifics above re how maintenance runs.

Comment: @Gumbo Our maintenance scripts will sometimes employ API calls themselves using `CURL` which require the session to remain in tact, these may take place later on during the parent scripts execution and thus are expired by the time they come around. The session contains info necessary for permission checks.

Comment: @Wesley I'm not going to get into the specifics, it's not pertinent to this question, let's just assume that it's necessary.

Comment: `$_SESSION` should remain intact even if the session’s data entry is deleted by the garbage collector, and should be restored on runtime shutdown.

Comment: @WesleyMurch  Our session store is actually in the DB, but that shouldn't have any bearing on this.  The question is, will the timestamp associated with the session be updated by simply updating a var stored in the session, or do I need to use a specific function to for lack of a better term `touch` the session.

Comment: @Gumbo The session record may persist after the garbage collector empties `data`, but what's the use of it if the session is expired and no longer able to access protected resources required to do it's job?  The simple fact is, the session must remain active throughout the process regardless of time, so I need something to touch the session timestamp.  I'm trying to avoid having to execute a CURL call every N records during a long loop and thus we get back to my question: is updating a session var value enough, or is there a function call.  If both of these are false, is there another option?

Comment: My point is: even if the session expires and the garbage collector removes the data, it should have no influence on the currently active session represented by `$_SESSION`. The data should be stored back on runtime shutdown (`session_write_close`). Only if you require another call of `session_start` on the already expired session you’ll get an empty `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @Gumbo As I mentioned in the comments above, some of the maintenance tasks that potentially follow a long running one use `CURL` to run tasks, and so while the parent process would continue to run and have access to a valid session insofar as it's still running, any remote calls to child tasks which would expect a valid session to still be active would fail due to the session data having been expunged.

Comment: @oucil have you considered overwriting your php.ini session length during runtime in your cron jobs?

Comment: @AndreschSerj Wouldn't work for a few reasons, first is that it would affect all users which is a security issue in our multi-tenant environment, but we're also running on N+1 application servers and sessions are not sticky across our load-balancers so there's no guarantee that the machine running the parent process would be the same running the child call.

Comment: @oucil Maybe simple PHP Sessions are not what you are looking for :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So despite several solutions being floated, none met our requirements, they were either more overhead than they were worth, had security concerns, or would have required a lot of work to implement across a massive application.

In PHP's case, $_SESSION is just a copy of the data stored in the session record until the request ends and new data overwrites the old, and so any manipulation of $_SESSION has no effect on the actual session records expiry in the system.

Because in our unique case we use MySQL for session management the easiest answer was to create our own `touch_session()` method with the simple query:

```
UPDATE sessions SET expiration = NOW() WHERE Session_ID = 'ABC123'
```

NB, our garbage collection uses NOW() - 30min to expire records, thus the setting of the expiry to NOW() in the query above.

This quick method can now be added to any potential long running maintenance scripts at points where it will be called often enough to avoid session expiry, but not often enough to add any overt overhead.

Hope this helps anyone else in similar situations.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, you can use curl to access another script that *touches* the session

**touch.php**

```
<?php
session_name('theNameOfYourSessionId');
session_start();
```

call this with curl like this in your maintanance script like this:

```
$sid = session_id();
exec('user curl -XGET https://domain.com/maintenance.php?theNameOfYourSessionId='.$sid)
```

This should do the trick.

Instead of curl you also just use [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead to avoid problems with curl.

```
$sid = session_id();
file_get_contents('https://domain.com/maintenance.php?theNameOfYourSessionId='.$sid);
```

Another approach would be to simply accept that sessions might be dead and reanimate them from the database. As you mentioned, you work with several app servers and you need a multiple app server solution anyway,

So why not use the provided session id as an identifier in your database and store the session content there? When you enter a script and the desired session is empty, call the database and restore it.

Comment: This is the best of the worst solutions due to two factors, the overhead of making additional CURL calls, as well as the potential for a CURL error for whatever reason which would halt the script all together unless I go to even more trouble to deal with error handling.  I'm hoping for a quick answer like "sure, use `touch_session();`", or `$_SESSION['var'] = microtime();`

Comment: @oucil as far as i know and as far as researching php.net goes, something like touch_session does not exist. sorry. I did an edit adding file_get_contents as an option. Maybe that is better for you.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, they're both valid and would work based on the question I asked.  Although, FYI, `file_get_contents()` is essentially socket based and works similarly to `curl` and thus would be susceptible to the same overhead and potential for comm errors.  Still, they're options, so thanks for that.

Comment: @oucil Well since there is no touch_php_session and my answer is valid, please consider accepting it and thus marking this question as answered.

Comment: I appreciate your input Andresch, but when taking into account the updated information in the question, which I also mentioned here, that these solutions have major pitfalls, overhead, a requirement to do a lot of error handling, etc.  I'll certainly +1 this when I'm ready to select an answer, but I'll leave it open a little longer to see if there are any other ideas.  In the interim, I went ahead and created my own static `touch_session()` method which manually updates the timestamp in our sessions table, a benefit of using the DB to manage our sessions. I don't think I'll see better.